# How to edit a macro in excel 2010 so that the filter criteria is: not equal to blanks?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to creating macros so my apologies if my question is not very clear. I have recorded a macro do autofilter a spreadsheet. What I need it to do is to not include the blanks in the filter. Considering that each sheet has different values inputted the way the macro is setup right now is based on the first sheet I used. 
This is what the code looks like:

```
Range ("B7:B8) .Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$7:$N$38").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "1.00", "13.00", "2.00", "3.00", "3.50", "42.50", "6.00", "7.00", "Total"), Operator _
    :=xlFilterValues
```

So what I think it should be is changing the Criteria in order for it to not select blanks instead of selecting exact values (that will be different in every sheet).

Does anyone know how to do this? and please let me know if you need any other information.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use Greater then 0?

Comment: What about numbers less than 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to edit a macro in excel 2010 so that the filter criteria is: not equal to blanks?

in continuation to my comment, what if the value is <0?

The best way is to use this

```
Criteria1:="<>"
```

FOLLOWUP FROM COMMENTS

Try this

`Yourrng.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="<>", Criteria2:="<>-"`

I did this

```
Myrng.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="<>", Criteria2:="<>0"
```

Comment: This is what I had thought initially but it did not work, but the <0 will work fine for this particular macro.

Comment: I have tried and tested it :) Can you show me the data that you have?

Comment: Also ensure that the cells are actually blank. To test of the cell is blank on not, use this formula `=Len(A1)` Assuming that Cell A1 looks blank. It should return `0`. If it doesn't then the cell is not blank.

Comment: Yes, that's where my explanation wasn't clear, in fact they are not blank cells, they are cells with a sum formula in them and if there are no values entered in that range it will return a "-" in that cell. So technically not blank. What I really would like the macro to do is to filter out all the blanks and "-". So I guess I would need to add a second Criteria to it.

Comment: Although your last suggestion did not work in this case, it allowed me to play with it a bit, so check the edited post for what I came up with and this now works.

Comment: If your cell has "-" then I am surprised as to why `<>0` works for you. I tried and tested it with line and it worked.

Comment: I know, it was a surprise for me to I'm glad it did work, but it was thanks to your help that I figured it out for this case. As I'm using a sheet that wasn't created by me, I'm happy that I can make it work with what I have.

Answer (score 0):

For number you can use:

```
Criteria1:=">0"
```

For Text you could use:

```
Criteria1:="=*"
```